# IIS Server 404 pages wordpress and video 404 page

Tags: wordpress, iis, permalinks, buddypress

I Am trying to set up a WordPress blog with BuddyPress, My permalinks have `example.com/index.php/pagename`, I've never had "index.php" in my permalinks

also any BuddyPress page is a 404 page, and I put a video on the `IIS` website and that also gives a 404 error.

Any suggestions are welcomed ? I can not really set up my website with these problems.

Answer (score -1):

try this. may be its work

all file should be under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder